# Late-2010s cartoon about a male middle-aged monster-hunting chosen one set in the modern day

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm searching for a cartoon released in the late 2010s. It may have been from a minor streaming service or small TV network. There was at least one season. I don't know if there was a second.

The main character was a middle aged, male 'chosen one' (in the mould of Buffy the Vampire Slayer) selected to fight monsters. He dressed in cheap black suits and was visually past is prime. He wasn't fat. The setting was modern day but with secret monsters - like Supernatural or, again, Buffy.

The cartoon has action heavy, with blood and gore, but I don't think there was any nudity.

Comment: @gidds: Yeah, I initially read that as being about a middle-aged monster hunting the chosen one. "Oof... better stretch out those hip flexors before heading out. I always seem to run into Hunter Johnson at the deli, and it's so hard to keep up with these six legs when he starts yelling 'Parkour!' and bouncing off random things."

Comment: Good news, Amazon Prime is supposed to air a second season later this year.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Might it be *[Gary and His Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gary_and_His_Demons)*?

[image: Promo image for Gary and His Demons]

> The series opens on aging Gary as he chases what he thinks is his last demon. After a disappointing failed capture resulting in him injuring an innocent homeless boy, Gary returns to the Demon Ministry to attend his own retirement party - his second retirement party in thirty years since Chosen One status is only meant to last fifteen years. Shortly after an underwhelming retirement speech his boss, Leslie, reveals to him that they've once again failed to find his replacement, and she asks him to serve one more term as Chosen One - which would mean fighting until he turns 60. The show revolves around Gary's adventures in demon hunting while also dealing with the frustration of being unable to retire.

Found with a search for `cartoon middleaged "chosen one" monsters`

### Trailer